# How to iterate through a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
[{'doc_name': 'Test Document 1','doc_url': 'https:SOMETHING/SE.html',
'timestamp': '2017-06-21T19:58:34+00:00'} {'doc_name': 'Test Document 
2','doc_url': 'https://SOMETHING/test-2-docs,'timestamp': '2017-06-
21T19:58:34+00:00'}]
```

And would like to iterate through it with a new function:

```
for i, key in enumerate(doc_list):
    doc_url = 'https:stuff'.format(doc_name)
    body += '<li>\n<a href="{0}"  datetime 
    {1}>\n</li>\n'.format(doc_url, timestamp)
```

However when I run the code above I receive the error:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Show `doc_list`. Apparently it's a function. It can't be that bit of data at the top. Also, you don't appear to be using `i` or `key` in the loop.

Comment: I have a feeling that `doc_list` is a function that returns the list you've shown us. Change your code to `for i, key in enumerate(doc_list()):`

Comment: The code in general is quite broken - what is `doc_name`?

Comment: Thanks, @inspectorG4dget solved the problem!

Comment: Correct assumption

Answer (score 1):

The code below works, so I think as highlighted by Carcigenicate and InspectorG4dget above, doc_list is a function and not the structure you pasted.  You probably need to add () to call it.

```
list = [{'doc_name': 'Test Document 1','doc_url': 'https:SOMETHING/SE.html','timestamp': '2017-06-21T19:58:34+00:00'},
        {'doc_name': 'Test Document 2','doc_url': 'https://SOMETHING/test-2-docs','timestamp': '2017-06-21T19:58:34+00:00'}]

for idx, obj in enumerate(list):
    print(obj['doc_name'])
```

Also, if you wanted to pull out the doc_name you'd need to do it as a key on the hash, as I've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you're looking for this:

```
doc_list = [{'doc_name': 'Test Document 1','doc_url': 'https:SOMETHING/SE.html', 'timestamp': '2017-06-21T19:58:34+00:00'}, 
    {'doc_name': 'Test Document2','doc_url': 'https://SOMETHING/test-2-docs', 'timestamp': '2017-06-21T19:58:34+00:00'}]

body = ""
for i, d in enumerate(doc_list):
    doc_url = 'https:stuff'.format(d['doc_name'])
    body += '<li>\n<a href="{0}"  datetime{1}>\n</li>\n'.format(d['doc_url'], d['timestamp'])

print body
```

which results in:

```
>>> <li>
>>> <a href="https:SOMETHING/SE.html"  datetime2017-06-21T19:58:34+00:00>
>>> </li>
>>> <li>
>>> <a href="https://SOMETHING/test-2-docs"  datetime2017-06-21T19:58:34+00:00>
>>> </li>
```